# Is it mandatory for a factory to have a superclass?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, service, factory

I'm making a spring boot app which operates with many SOAP services.

I created 2 factories that generate the requests for each one of the possible soap operations I will use, however, they both receive different arguments. I didn't make a superclass  for them yet and I injected them to my service main class. Is this a good design? Maybe 'factory' is a bad name for them.

```
private RetrieveComissionsFactory retrieveComissionsFactory;
private EditCommissionsFactory editCommissionsFactory;
private BGBAHeaderFactory bgbaHeaderFactory;

@Autowired
public SoapServiceImpl(RetrieveComissionsFactory retrieveComissionsFactory, EditCommissionsFactory editCommissionsFactoryy) {
    this.retrieveComissionsFactory = retrieveComissionsFactory;
    this.editCommissionsFactory = editCommissionsFactory;
}
```

Is this a good approach? Or there is any other way to use them?

I'm using these two factories to create the requests I must send to SOAP, and like I said, they receive different arguments.

Use examples:

```
CommissionsRetrieveRequest request = retrieveComissionsFactory.createRetrieveCommissionsRequest(date);

RegisterCommissionRequest request = editCommissionsFactory.createRegisterCommissionsRequest(change, operador,
                authorizing, fromDate);
```

Comment: The word "factory" by itself doesn't really mean anything. There are a number of formal patterns that _include_ the word factory in their titles, but there is no single pattern named "factory". If you are trying to apply one specific pattern, I would suggest naming it explicitly; otherwise, I find the word factory only adds noise and confusion.

Comment: In this specific scenario, why doesn't the `SoapServiceImpl` own the logic for generating requests? Why is a middleman necessary to separate that logic? And if this code is currently working for you, are you looking for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I separated the responsability of each request to different classes because each request use some inner objects with same class name.

One request use a: ar.com.banco.requests.Register.Commission.Comision
The other use: ar.com.banco.requests.Edition.Commission.Comision

And the code imo is gonna be pretty ugly if I import just one and instance the other as
"ar.com.banco.requests.edition.Commission.Comision Comision = new ...."

And this happens with many classes, like 3 or 4, not just Comision. That imports are from the autogenerated classes of cxf, I can't change them